# Fetch text of UILabel from UIButton

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibutton, uilabel, buttonclick

I am new to `iPhone`,

There are lots of button in my app and on each button i have one `UILabel`, when user clicks on any button i want to fetch corresponding text of that label from that button.

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{ 
    NSString *Txt=  sender.titleLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"Txt=%@",Txt);
}
```

but my log shows: `Txt=null`

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: i think there is no need of uilabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume u might have subviewed label on button like this:

```
 UILabel *lblText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:button.frame];
 lblText.text = @"NameofButton";
 [button addSubview:lblText];
 [lblText release];
```

Now button click event will be like this:

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{ 
  //NSArray *arrSubViews = [sender subviews];
  for (id anObject in [sender subviews]) {
      if([anObject isKindOfClass: [UILabel class]]){
          UIlabel *myLabel = anObject;
          NSString *Txt=  myLabel.text;
          NSLog(@"Txt=%@",Txt);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are setting the title with:

```
[button setTitle:@"your title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```